# sharepoint dropdown change event based on TD ID

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, jquery

in My custom form i have my HTMl like this

```
  <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody" id="Type_x0020_of_x0020_Request"><span dir="none"><select name="ctl00$ctl33$g_ad15cfef_4ccd_4d9f_8ab2_ed089bcb96c6$ff81$ctl00$DropDownChoice" id="ctl00_ctl33_g_ad15cfef_4ccd_4d9f_8ab2_ed089bcb96c6_ff81_ctl00_DropDownChoice" title="Type of Request" class="ms-RadioText">
                        <option selected="selected" value="Please Select">Please Select</option>
                        <option value="508 Remediation for BPHC Website">508 Remediation for BPHC Website</option>
                        <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
                        <option value="Presentation Development">Presentation Development</option>
                        <option value="Speakers Bureau">Speakers Bureau</option>
                        <option value="Webinar (Adobe Connect Assistance)">Webinar (Adobe Connect Assistance)</option>
                        <option value="BPHC Website">BPHC Website</option>
                        <option value="Writing/Editing">Writing/Editing</option>

                    </select><br></span></td>
```

How can i select the Dropdown and trigger chnage event based on the  ID "Type_x0020_of_x0020_Request" ? I tried like this but change event is not working

```
$('#Type_x0020_of_x0020_Request span select').change(function () {

            typeOfRequestvalue = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
            alert(typeOfRequestvalue);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The id `"Type_x0020_of_x0020_Request"` is for the `<td> element` not `<select> element` (drop down list).

The id of your drop down list - `<select> element` is `ctl00_ctl33_g_ad15cfef_4ccd_4d9f_8ab2_ed089bcb96c6_ff81_ctl00_DropDownChoice`.

You cannot get the selected option value from `the <td> element`.

And the [change](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp) event only works on `<input>, <textarea> and <select> elements`.

Use script below:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){
    //by title
    $("select[title='Type of Request'").change(function(){
       var selected = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
       alert(selected);
    });
    //by id
    $("select[id='ctl00_ctl33_g_ad15cfef_4ccd_4d9f_8ab2_ed089bcb96c6_ff81_ctl00_DropDownChoice'").change(function(){
       var typeOfRequestvalue = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
       alert(typeOfRequestvalue);
    });
});
</script>
```